# [Vue warn]: <transition> can only be used on a single element. Use <transition-group> for lists

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I am using `Transition` for `Breaking News` but transition is not working!

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <a :href="news.news_main_link" class="news" v-for="news in newsList" :key="news.id">{{ news.news_title }}</a>
</transition>
```

`newsList` is an array.

```
newsList = [
{
  id: 1,
  news_main_link: 'link1',
  news_title: 'Test Title'
}
]
```

Didn't find the problem.

Comment: I think you should use `transition-group` instead of `transition`...

Comment: @Jax-p, Yes. You are right. But then all `<a></a>` are coming in one row. :-(

Comment: Yes, but it's loop. `v-for="news in newsList"` It doesn't care how many items there are in the array.

Comment: If we can set if else so that every time it will render only one item then the problem will solve. But in for loop it's not possible to use `v-if`